# CoAP.Net Throws a StackOverflow Exception

Tags: .net-core, coap

I'm trying to use CoAP.Net using the most basic example could ever be

```
var server = new CoapServer();

server.Start();
Console.ReadKey();
```

However, even for this simple test the application terminates due to a StackOverflow exception
I took a look at the start method on their GitHub repository and couldn't find a single line of code that might cause a StackOverflow exception

I'm using version 1.1.0 on a .NET Core 2.1 project running on a MacOS machine and that makes me wonder if the library is still working